# How to subtract one timespan from another in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, timespan

I need to subtract one timespan from another.

Example: timespan1 is from January 1, 2014 to January 15, 2014. timespan2 is from January 5 to January 10. I would like to get something like:

```
timespan1 - timespan2 = 01/01 to 01/04 AND 01/11 to 01/15
```

Is there a gem that I could use for something like this? If I wanted to do this manually I'd have to consider a lot of cases (timespans are overlapping/not overlapping, overlapping partially/totally etc.) If not a gem, maybe an idea of an algorithm simpler than considering all those cases separately?

Comment: Define subtraction between timespans. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your example using regular Arrays of Date objects. Assuming you only use days I believe this will work pretty well in the cases you are interested in. That is:

```
require 'date'

a = [* Date.new(2014,1,1) .. Date.new(2014,1,15)]
b = [* Date.new(2014,1,5) .. Date.new(2014,1,10)]

diff = a - b

diff.each { |date| puts date.strftime('%d %B %Y') }

# Output:
# 01 January 2014
# 02 January 2014
# 03 January 2014
# 04 January 2014
# 11 January 2014
# 12 January 2014
# 13 January 2014
# 14 January 2014
# 15 January 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
r1 = (f1..l1)
r2 = (f2..l2)
```

where `f1`, `l1`, `f2` and `l2` are date objects (possibly converted from strings) or any other objects that can form a range. I assume you want to construct an array that includes all elements covered by `r1` that are not covered by `r2`. Note the result cannot necessarily be expressed as a range, as in some cases the elements covered by `r1` but not by `r2` are not contiguous, as when `r1 = (1..6)` and `r2 = (3..4)`, where the result is `[1,2,5,6]`.

**Code**

We can calculate the desired array directly from the endpoints of the two given ranges. There are six cases to consider, which are covered by a `case` statement.

```
def range_difference(r1, r2)
  f1, l1 = r1.first, r1.last
  f2, l2 = r2.first, r2.last
  case
  when l2 < f1
    (f1..l1).to_a
  when f2 <= f1 && f1 <= l2 && l2 < l1
    (l2+1..l1).to_a
  when f2 <= f1 && l1 <= l2
    []
  when f1 < f2 && f2 < l1 && l2 < l1
    (f1..f2-1).to_a + (l2+1..l1).to_a
  when f1 < f2 && f2 <= l1 && l2 >= l1
    (f1..f2-1).to_a
  else # f2 > l1
    (f1..l1).to_a
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
range_difference((5..10),(2..7))
  #=> [8, 9, 10]
range_difference((5..10),(2..10))
  #=> []
range_difference((5..10),(6..8))
  #=> [5, 9, 10]
range_difference((5..10),(6..10))
  #=> [5]
range_difference((5..10),(7..12))
  #=> [5, 6]
range_difference((5..10),(10..12))
  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
range_difference((5..10),(11..12))
  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```